# Bootloader/Grub can't boot but recovery works but still can't boot

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

Hi I have an issue with running ubuntu on sdcard

The usb is 8gb and partitioned into :
sda1 : 900MB (FAT32)
sda5 : 512MB (swap)
sda6 : 6GB (EXT4) root

Ubuntu 15.04 is already installed.

But when I boot from this sdcard, I get into "grub" (is this the one with the list boot : Ubuntu, Advanced Options for Ubuntu, Memory Test etc?)

I can access that page, but when I hit enter on Ubuntu, I get the :
[qupte]Error failure reading sector 0xa361c0 from 'hd0'
Press any key to continue. [/quote]

At this point it hangs, I can't "press any key" it doesn't do anything.

1. Now, if I press the reset button on my computer and do exactly the same thing again, I'll be able to boot perfectly into Ubuntu. But if I shutdown Ubuntu and reboot and access that "grub" page again, I'll run into the above error again two times out of three.
2. Another way is to run "Advanced Options for Ubuntu" then choosing "Resume boot". It will boot into Ubuntu fine except the graphics is not full screen, just a little window in the middle.

Its really a hit and miss, sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.

I'm not sure what's going on. If I can find some help to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you have the capacity to check the sd card for corruption or damage?

Comment: I have checked, with imageusb and with h2testw.exe, it is not damaged

Answer (score 0):

SD cards are accessed by circuitry on the computer's motherboard (or an SD card reader attached by USB, etc.). This circuitry requires drivers, and not all of them are well-supported in Linux. The nature of your error smells to me like a buggy driver. If so, you may just have to live with it until a driver fix is released. [Filing a bug report](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) may help, but you'll need to be very specific about what type of hardware you've got. (Typing `sudo lshw > lshw.txt` and attaching the resulting `lshw.txt` file may be helpful.)